# Error: Simulator architecture is unsupported by the app. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop, appium-java

Appium - iOS - Macbook M1 chip

Appium inspector: 1.21.0

Encountered internal error running command: Error: Simulator architecture is unsupported by the '/var/folders/02/pmtd5x_51_34lk5hp_1h4c000000gn/T/2022327-78661-1k3io4.g3jny/------.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode.

{
"platformName": "iOS",
"platformVersion": "15.0",
"deviceName": "iPhone 12",
"app": "/Users/sumit.kathuria/Documents/7eeb29ec-6363-4ebd-ba8f-5496edd414d1.ipa",
"automationName": "XCUITest",
"version": "1.21.0"
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMWt1.jpg)